# global state across forked processes

Tags: c, multithreading, rust, multiprocessing, fork

I have to write a plugin for an C application. I want to do that in rust. The problem that I'm facing is that the C application uses `fork()` for multithreading and that my knowledge about how multithreading with fork and shared memory and so on works on a lower level.

What I'm trying to achive is to have one GLOBAL state that needs to be a bit mutable in the end. I want use an globally accessable [evmap](https://crates.io/crates/evmap) ReadHandleFactory that gives access to some [libssh2](https://crates.io/crates/ssh2) connections, to get some information from a ssh server. For writing to the evmap I was planning on [spawning my own rust thread](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/). And sending messages to it throug a  [crossbeam](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.7.2/crossbeam/) channel.

The problem boils down that for rust every process that was created by a fork is like it's executing on it's own and like all other processes don't exist. Demonstrated with the following code:

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "cinteroptest"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["usbpc"]
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name = "cinteroptest"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
libc = "0.2.62"
lazy_static = "1.4.0"
```

Rust:

```rust
#[marco_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
    static ref TEST: u32 = init();
}

fn init() -> u32 {
    println!("Initializing!");
    5
}

#[no_mangle]
extern "C" fn foo() {
    println!("Hello world! {}", *TEST)
}
```

C:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>    

typedef void *foo();

int main() {
    void *myso = dlopen("./libcinteroptest.so", RTLD_NOW);
    foo *func = dlsym(myso, "foo");
    fork();
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

To compile the C code:

```
gcc test.c -ldl
```

Output:

```
Initializing!
Initializing!
Hello world! 5
Hello world! 5
```

Is there a way for easy global state in rust in these circumstances?

Comment: In C, you’d probably use shared memory.  I don’t know whether Rust supports that.

Comment: Is servo/ipc_channel insufficient?

Comment: `fork()` creates new **processes**, not **threads**. If you want global state between processes, you have to use shared memory or another IPC mechanism.

Comment: [`shared_memory`](https://docs.rs/shared_memory/0.8.2/shared_memory/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: the example you provided only demonstrated that you are not familiar with how `fork` works.  What exactly do you want from your program?

Comment: Yes I don’t really know much about C and not much about systems programming. I come from kotlin/jvm and python. For me a global means that within one application everything that accesses this global access the same thing. Here that would mean only initializing my lazy static once.